# How to generate modular css key like component_cssclass_uniquekey in react library

Tags: reactjs

We created multiple react libraries and by default it came with modular css which was great. But after few composite components developed and when we started integrating into create-react-app we saw same module css keynames present in multiple composite components, below is an example to better explain

- Create-react-library1

  - style.module.css

    - layout in dist this css key generated as _2GhQJ
- Create-react-library2

  - style.module.css

    - layout in dist this css key generated as _2GhQJ

When added above modules as dependency in Create-react-app, these are creating conflict.
Based on documentation i thought modular css will generate className as {componentName}*{cssClass}*{uniquekey}

I'm not using webpack as it just a react library, i have been researching but couldn't any exmaples on how i can solve this. We're suing typescript.

I really appreciate any suggestions or solutions